# Excel Cloning Cells (that have Conditional Formatting)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

As seen in the table, from the input you type in column **Rate Value**, a corresponding cell in **Scoring Guide** will be highlighted. I've done that with conditional formatting. Now what I want is to **clone** the whole table depending on how many employees we have.

I don't know if **cloning** is the right term to be used.

Here is the conditional formatting I used.

[image]

I dont actually know how to **clone**. I don't even know if it is possible. If anyone can help me, that will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry about the formatting. i dont have enough reputations yet to post images.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cloning? You want N number of  these tables for each employee?

Comment: @Gangula, I checked the images. The images were changed when someone made an edit. I updated it.

Yes, i want the table to be cloned for N number of employees

Comment: It sounds and looks like you want one new sheet per person.  If that is what you want, then right click the sheet name on the tab at the bottom of the finished sheet, select move or copy, then check the create copy box, and select a destination.  You can can keep your "clones" all together in one workbook, send them to other workbooks, or even use them to create new workbooks.

Comment: no, not like that. i want everything in a single sheet. maybe ill use countif or count then, the **form** will be cloned accordingly.